# How to install Ubuntu from DVD to Hard Drive without partitioning, that has DOS & no Windows?

Tags: system-installation

I have bought a new laptop specifically without Windows, which has only DOS.

I understand how to prioritize the boot order in BIOS but in doing that, my understanding is that the OS on the DVD is only installed into the Memory. Correct me if I'm wrong. I want the OS on the DVD installed onto the Hard Drive.

The question "How do I install Ubuntu?" refers to creating a partition in the Hard Drive to share with Windows. I don't want Windows. My computer does have DOS which I now realize needs to be partitioned if I want to keep it.

The installation was simple. Ubuntu gave the option of "Trying" (leaving in the memory) or "Installing" (installing onto the Hard Drive) and then gave the option of leaving the existing FreeDOS (DOS & Ubuntu) or removing it (Ubuntu only)

Thanks Guys.

Comment: Do you want to replace DOS or keep it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: You made an incorrect assumption that Windows (and only Windows) requires its own partition. But any installed OS requires its own partition.

Answer (score 2):

A live CD can do both, you can run it in memory, or you can click the icon in the GUI to install it to a hard drive.

During your installation of Ubuntu, you'll have the ability to set up partitioning to how you want it.  Assuming you're not going to keep FreeDos and you don't intend on installing windows later, you can let Ubuntu handle the partitioning and use the entire disk.

Answer (score 0):

If you boot from the disc it should open a window that gives you the option to "Try Ubuntu", which runs the OS from the disc, or you can "Install Ubuntu", which will install it to the hard drive, and also give you the option to overwrite any other systems on the hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

The "running from memory" refers to the try option provided at boot from DVD.

Providing that you only want Ubuntu on this system the details about partitioning are NOT required. The install package on the DVD will replace the entire contents of the hard drive. Quoted sections from a link to [Ubuntu Graphical Install Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall)

> If you want to install Ubuntu over your entire hard drive, select
>   Erase disk and install Ubuntu, then select the hard drive that you
>   want to install Ubuntu. Warning: this will erase all data and systems
>   that are currently on the disk

If your desire is to maintain the DOS installation you will be provided an opportunity during the install procedure to select install along side.

> If you want to install Ubuntu alongside you other systems (eg
>   alongside Windows), select the Install Ubuntu alongside them.

If neither of the above 2 options is exactly what you desire then...

> If you want to manually setup your partitioning scheme, , select the
>   Something else option. You will find further advice on the [DiskSpace
>   page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace)

.